# creating zoom in effect on clicking the thumbnail or link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[This link has a carousel similar to what I'm trying to implement](https://amazingcarousel.com/examples/javascript-image-scroller-id9/)
I have a basic slider for images.

[Something like this Example](https://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });
  
 var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
 var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
 var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
 var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
 
 $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
 
 $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
 
    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

```css
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #8A8A8A;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 600px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #fff;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #fff;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```

I want the slider to open upon clicking on a button/link. I am new to jQuery, so I'm not sure if that's possible using onclick event. Can someone please tell me the basic idea that goes behind this implementation? Thank you!

Comment: Basic idea: use some of jQuery lightbox scripts -> http://fancybox.net/ this one is pretty nice, imho. On example page - they use one of many variations of that script, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a button in your HTML and use it to show your `slides` on click. Also wrap your complete Slider related HTML inside a div and hide the dive initially. Like below.

```
<button id="showSlider">Show me the slider</button>

<div id="sliderWrapper" style="display:none;">
 <!--Your current HTML goes here-->
</div>
```

With this in place, Now put all the current logic in your scripts inside a function. Lets call this function when ever we click the button.

```
function SliderScripts() {
 //all your current scripts goes here
}
```

Now modify your document ready function to below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#showSlider').on('click', function() { // button click event
    SliderScripts();  // run the sliders scripts
    $('#sliderWrapper').show(); / show the slider.
    $(this).hide(); //hide the button
  });

});
```

Here is a working snippet.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#showSlider').on('click', function() {
    SliderScripts();
    $('#sliderWrapper').show();
    $(this).hide();
  });

});

function SliderScripts() {
  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });

}
```

```css
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #8A8A8A;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 600px;
  list-style: none;
}
#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}
a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="showSlider">Show me the slider</button>

<div id="sliderWrapper" style="display:none;">
  <div id="slider">
    <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
    <a href="#" class="control_prev">
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li>SLIDE 1</li>
      <li style="background: #fff;">SLIDE 2</li>
      <li>SLIDE 3</li>
      <li style="background: #fff;">SLIDE 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="slider_option">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried replacing the button in above code with svg polygon and on click doesn't make the slider appear. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So if I attach the id to the svg tag itself, then it works fine. But if I have multiple polygons in a single svg tag, then I would have access each polygon separately, I want each of them to open a different slider. The best answer I found was based on position of polygons, it can be done. But it's tedious and I don't have better ideas

Comment: @Sreenidhi may be you can set same classes to all your polygons and write your script on class instead of if

Comment: Yeah Thanks! here's a useful link I found : https://css-tricks.com/click-svg-to-focus/

Answer (score 0):

Add class the slider on click and style the slide element with css something like

```
element.active {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

then the element will pop out from the slide and you can add anything you want to the active class of the element. and in your example click the slide element

```
  $('#slider li').on('click', function () {
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
```

the css for the active class

```
li.active {
     position: fixed !important;
     top: 50px;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     bottom: 50px;
}
```

for simple overlay

```
li.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  left: -50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}
```